# How would you solve this system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&x+y+z+u=5\\
&y+z+u+v = 1\\
&z+u+v+x = 2\\
&u+v+x+y = 0\\
&v+x+y+z = 4
\end{align*}\right.$$

How do I solve this system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: 
What will you get after you add all equations, and simplify the left side?
(x+y+z+u+v= ?)

From that, can you find x,y,z,u,v?

Another way (more general) is using linear algebra (it's a standard exercise in any linear algebra course)

Comment: Thanks!! I've solved it. v=-2; x= 2; y= 1; z= 3; u= -1;